# EntityNotFoundException error for get_column_statistics_for_table method in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am trying to pull metadata from a table in S3 location. I am trying to use get_column_statistics_for_table() method in AWS glue but its giving me EntityNotFoundException error.

I am able to use other methods such as - create_crawler(), start_crawler() etc. The get_column_statistics_for_table() method uses just 4 arguments out of which only 3 are required - database name, table name and column names. I know I am passing the correct arguments because I directly copied them from the AWS console. I have searched on SO and on other website but I haven't find this particular question.

Am I required to make a Glue "connection" to S3 ??

Code so far -

```
client = boto3.client('glue', region_name="us-east-1")
response = client.get_column_statistics_for_table(
    DatabaseName='Name_of_Database',
    TableName='Name_of_my_table',
    ColumnNames=[
        'Column_name_1'
    ]
)
print(response)

response that I am getting --
{'ColumnStatisticsList': [], 'Errors': [{'ColumnName': 'Column_name_1', 'Error': {'ErrorCode': 'EntityNotFoundException', 'ErrorMessage': 'Statistics do not exist for this column'}}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'Some_alphanumeric no', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': 'common HTTP Headers'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for replying. I have edited my post and added the code.